# URL prefix for Apache's RewriteRule patterns

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if there is any Apache directive to automatically add a given prefix to all RewriteRule patterns (and possibly also RewriteCond patterns), similar to RewriteBase for substitutions of relative urls.

To put this into a context - I want to run my php application under a url sub-folder, say we `http://example.com/my-app/`. In the Apache virtual host I set

```
Alias /myapp "<path-to-my-app-source-dir>"
```

as I want to run a different app under `http://example.com`. In the `.htaccess` under the my-app source folder, I added `RewriteBase /my-app` so I don't have to explicitly put `my-app` in RewriteRule substitutions. I haven't found any similar directive to specify prefix for patterns, so the following rules

```
RewriteRule ^my-app/foo/(.+)$ foo.php?x=$1
RewriteRule ^my-app/.*$ index.php [L]
```

could be specified as

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.+)$ foo.php?x=$1
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Is there one? Or is there overall a better solution for this set up?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just asking is there a better way to do this? There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it now. IMO I wouldn't use .htaccess at all. I would put all my rules in the VirtualHost. The performance is better with .htaccess turned off.

Comment: Yes, my question was more about if there is better way to solve this. For example if I decide later to change the base url, then I would have to change all rewrite rules. Thanks for your answer.